# Overwrite a file on S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am developing a feature where we need to back up our files on S3 bucket with the key pattern as **"tmp/yyyy-mm-dd.file_type.fileName"**

Now if I am running my app today for backing up the fileName "abc.txt", it will store that as the pattern specified.

Let's say tomorrow "abc.txt" is updated and the updated file now needs to be backed up on S3. Thus, it will be pushed with a different timestamp but with the same fileName present in key of our bucket.

So what should be done such that there is no redundancy on S3 bucket and the file should be overwritten?

Comment: Keeping the file name as is in the key will lead to issues, when you have similar file names coming from different sources. Above that, the key-pattern makes it backed up as a new file. May be you should avoid the date?

Comment: In order to have such a feature, can't we delete the existing key and push a new one with the latest timestamp

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to implement **de-duplication** so that the same file is not stored multiple times.

**Amazon S3 does not provide de-duplication as a feature**. Your software would need to recognize such duplication and implement this capability itself.

Alternatively, you might want to use **commercial backup software** that already has this capability in-built.

Example: [MSP36 Backup (formerly CloudBerry Backup)](https://www.msp360.com/backup.aspx)